# Create a recursive tree when source data is not organized in a hierarchy at all (PHP + SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, xml, laravel

Despite I've checked a lot of StackOverflow questions, as well as Google, I can't find any solution for this. *(any solution which I can understand and be able to do)*.

### The status quo

1. I cannot alter source database (but I would if there's not any other way).
2. Items of the hierarchy are into separated tables. (I have not a master hierarchy table).
3. If I query one of those tables, I have a relation of an item and its parent, but between diferent tables, those items doesn't share its parenting.

### Relation to achieve:

- Country

  - Region

    - City

      - And so on ...

### My starting point

Source data is in the following tables (depicted as `table => columns`)

```
country_table => id
region_table => id, country_id
city_table => id, region_id
... and so on ...
```

But when I query&join these tables, they don't share a "master" parent in any way. D'oh!

### Solutions I've thought so far

- Screw the "cannot alter source database" and build a proper hierarchy table (following the guides from an answer to this question: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree?rq=1)
- Worst never-ever do solution (*if it can be called a solution at all*): Hardcode the tree hierarchy, parenting all I can in each table and then parenting table by table.**Con:** Unmaintenable code, the deeper the hierarchy goes, the longest the lines of code are. And if hierarchy changes you're screwed.

### **EDIT: Final decision (and solution)**

- I didn't thought about converting that array into an XML Object (using PHP's SimpleXMLElement).

Code:

```
function buildLocationTree()
{ 
    //We retrieve raw data from model (Laravelish style)
    $aLocations = WhateverModel::getLocations();

    $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

    //I add a root node called 'result'
    $oResult = $oXML->addChild('result');

    foreach ($aLocations as $oLocation)
    {   
        if (! ($oXML->xpath("//country[@id=" . $oLocation->CountryId . "]")))
        {
            $oCountry = $oResult->addChild('country', $oLocation->CountryName);
            $oCountry->addAttribute('id', $oLocation->CountryId );
        }

        if (! ($oXML->xpath("//region[@id=" . $oLocation->RegionId. "]")))
        {
            $oRegion = $oCountry->addChild('region', $oLocation->RegionName);
            $oRegion->addAttribute('id', $oLocation->RegionId );
        }

        //And so on... build many structures 'search in nodes + add child' as deep levels
     }

     return $oXML;
}
```

Then do whatever you need with the XML object... jsonize it, build a file...

I'd be nice to have some feedback or listen your thoughts about this solution! Is an acceptable one? Risky or prone to errors?

Comment: This is not true recursion because it is not potentially infinitely recursive nor is it reentrant: after `City` would be `Street` or `Subdivision` and then just `House number`. This is just an example of tedium ;)

Comment: So I suppose my question is: just how deep can this hierarchy go down? If you can't alter the database, then you have all the tables there, so you know exactly how far down it goes.

Comment: Right now, it goes down one more level deep, but it's planned (in a short timeframe) to have two additional levels of depth (which they still have to define, that's why are not yet). But yes, still it will have a finite depth. By the way, what do you mean by "_This is just an example of tedium_"? That I will have to craft the parenting "manually" ?

Comment: yes, unfortunately. Granted, you *could* hypothetically write some meta-code which would be recursive over raw database objects (e.g. `select * from information_schema.tables`) but that would not be worth the trouble because you'll likely need to have special-case handling for each entity.

Comment: Jeez... that's bad news then. However, I will try to make the tedious task _less_ tedious (will update if I find a fancy solution).

Comment: I don't recommend it: don't try to be smart, that's how bugs happen.